# Plotly - R - Export as vector graphics

Tags: r, svg, plot, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to export a plot using plotly as vector graphics.

```
library(plotly)
library(RSelenium)

p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()
export(p,"3d_test.svg",RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome"))
```

This results in a SVG file, but it seems like the plot is not really in vector graphics, rather an embedded image.

I can't really use a pixel image, so is there any way to actually export the plot?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know that there is, and [their website](https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/) indicates that vector graphics export is limited to paid users only.